# Lightning component working fine but input data is not getting added to salesforce database

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, soql, dml-operations

```
public class CreateLeadcls {
    @Auraenabled
    public static string createLead(Lead ldObj){
        System.debug('Lead::'+ldObj.FirstName);
        insert ldObj;
        return ldObj.FirstName;
    }
    @Auraenabled
    public static List<Lead> retrieveLeads(){
        return [select FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone from Lead order by createdDate desc limit 5];
    }
}
```

```xml
<aura:component controller="CreateLeadcls">
    <aura:attribute name="leadObj" type="Lead" default="{'sObjectType':'Lead',
                                                        'FirstName':'',
                                                        'LastName':'',
                                                        'Email':'',
                                                        'Phone':''
                                                        }"/>
    <aura:attribute name="leadFname" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="leadList" type="Lead[]"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.showLeads}"/>
    <div>
        Lead
    </div>
    <div>
        <Lightning:input type="text" label="First Name" placeholder="Enter First Name.." value="{!v.leadObj.FirstName}"/>
        <Lightning:input type="text" label="Last Name" placeholder="Enter Last Name.." value="{!v.leadObj.LastName}"/>
        <Lightning:input type="Email" label="Email" placeholder="Enter EmailId.." value="{!v.leadObj.Email}"/>
        <Lightning:input type="Phone" label="Phone" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number.." value="{!v.leadObj.Phone}"/>
        
        <Lightning:button label="Save" title="Save" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.doSave}"/>
    </div>
    
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.leadList}" var="ldobj" indexVar="index">
        <div>
            {!ldobj.FirstName} {!ldobj.LastName}
        </div>
    </aura:iteration>
    <div>
            Lead:{!v.leadObj.FirstName} has been created successfully.
        </div>
</aura:component>
```

```javascript
({
    doSave : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action=component.get("c.createLead");
        var leadList=component.get("v.leadList");
        action.setParams({'ldObj': component.get('v.leadObj')});
         action.setCallback(this,function(response){           
            component.set('v.leadFname',response.getReturnValue())
            leadList.splice(0,0,component.get('v.leadObj'));
            component.set("v.leadList",leadList);     
        });        
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    showLeads: function(component, event, helper){
        var action=component.get("c.retrieveLeads");
        action.setCallback(this,function(data){            
            component.set('v.leadList',data.getReturnValue())
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
})
```

```xml
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:LeadRecCreation/>
</aura:application>
```